# Rancher agent can't run on master server?

Tags: docker, agent, rancher

Using CentOS 7. Docker 1.12.6

Want to install Rancher cluster:

- master: 192.168.0.100
- node1: 192.168.0.101
- node2: 192.168.0.102

Installed rancher server on master host:

```
$ docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8080:8080 rancher/server:stable
```

Until now can access dashboard from browser:

http://192.168.0.100

Process:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                 ... PORTS
9021gn390q49    rancher/server:stable ... 3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

---

## Add Host

Want to add master self using self IP address, got command:

```
$ docker run -e CATTLE_AGENT_IP="192.168.0.100" -e CATTLE_HOST_LABELS='etcd=true&orchestration=true' --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher racher/agent:v1.2.2 http://192.168.0.100:8080/v1/scripts/AJFIOWAEJHOFGH289429:18347207210:xWIJFOHO02HGOEWIH
```

Then got bad information:

```
INFO: Running Agent Registration Process, ATTLE_URL=http://192.168.0.100:8080/v1
INFO: Attempting to connect to: http://192.168.0.100:8080/v1
ERROR: http://192.168.0.100:8080/v1 is not accessible
...
```

But ...

It can add agent from nodes servers! Why can't at master?

Maybe due to the proxy. How to fix it?

---

## Addition

I found `host.key` file in this path on nodes hosts:

> /var/lib/rancher/etc/ssl/

So they can run rightly.

But why not in master host machine?

Comment: it's probably the iptables issue, you probably have restriction on translating to public ip port from localhost

Comment: @AlexKarshin I have added these two ports: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT`, `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT`. But the same result.

Comment: restart rancher

Comment: @AlexKarshin I have tried many times. Deleted container, even deleted images. Downloaded again. They are all the same.

Comment: Actually, there are multiple threads on this issue on official rancher github and different approaches work for different people. Looks like there's no universal (or *right*) one.

Comment: @AlexKarshin I also read that. Maybe http 80 port? I am not sure now. Using curl was doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the host with `CATTLE_AGENT_IP="192.168.0.100"`?

Comment: The problem was firewalld. When close it, works well.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah any kind of firewalls/iptables rules which interfere can cause communication problems.